# ros-iron-nav-bringup not found

Tags: ros, ros2

I'm unable to install the package `ros-iron-nav2-bringup`,
I get `Unable to locate package ros-iron-nav2-bringup`

I successfully installed ros-iron-desktop, ros-iron-navigation2, ros-iron-slam-toolbox and some others.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I have no issue on my Ubuntu desktop computer also running 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is known, but cannot be fixed easily, because it is part of a complex dependency problem.

As [SteveMacenski](https://github.com/SteveMacenski) says on the [github issue report](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3766#issuecomment-1692131195):

> So theres a dependency missing in gazebo-land on ARM64 which is
> blocking everything from gazebo ros to turtlebot then to us. So
> unfortunately there's really nothing we can do about it here, but I'd
> recommend following up in that ticket if you wanted to help fix the
> issue. Else, building from source is your best bet. The issue isn't
> much to do with nav2_bringup as much as nothing in gazebo classic will
> work for you on ARM without compilation.